# Fake server for creating js apps

Tags: javascript, api, backbone.js, mocking

When I create a project (I create js app with backbone) sometimes server isn't ready to take me right response. We create our sides parallel. So I need in fake data for my requests. I need to collections and full restapi.

So I want to ask you, what is the good solution? Can I use couch db for example. I listen that their API is full and I can create collections and documents very easy. Also I try to use apiary.io but it's not so usefull. Tell me please how you resolve this problem?

Comment: CouchDB isn't a bad idea. It is easy to install (on Linux) and you can quickly set up a mock environment that is supported with normal HTTP. On top of that, there is a number of extensions that allow you to serve your own JavaScript applications through CouchDB itself.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [lineman.js](https://github.com/testdouble/lineman). It runs a node server so you can set up routes to return json data for just this type of scenario. There is a short intro [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmZ4XRErYAI) as well. This tool also does bundles and minifies js as well as less compilation. All of it is configurable since it drives through grunt.

Comment: +1 Lineman is a great way to develop. Especially when you don't have a server yet. Decoupled clients are the way to go.